# search filter in spring-boot-admin wallboard is missing values

Tags: spring-boot-admin

We have spring-boot-admin wallboard with approx 50 services. Each servicename is made up of 3 or 4 string-parts separated by a hyphen.
When i search with the 4th part of the servicename, then some servicenames are not visible on the wallboard. Without filter the servicename is visible on the wallboard.

Since the 4th part is an exact part of the complete servicename i would expect that it is shown in the wallboard.
For example one of the services is

```
remote-service-enrichment-mast
```

Searching for `mast` does not show the servicename on the wallboard.
However when changing the servicename to

```
local-service-enrichment-mast
```

and searching for `mast` then the new servicename is shown on the wallboard.

Why is the wallboard not showing my service when i enter part of the servicename in the searchfilter?

Comment: I can confirm that behaviour, seems to be a bug in Spring Boot Admin, the team will have a look

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/3187, the issue has been fixed and will be included in next release (probably 3.2.3).

Maybe there will be more tweaks to the search as it is using a fuzzy search and searching for substring should always find the matching entries.